# Is it unprofessional of me to play games before and after work, whilst at the office?

Tags: professionalism, united-kingdom

I'm a junior software developer in a small company(20-25 employees).

I get into work an hour early each day and leave a half hour later to avoid traffic however this leaves me with a conundrum, because I could work that extra hour and not get paid. I can browse websites like Facebook, Twitter or the Workplace Stack but I would rather be playing games on my phone or on my DS.

So my main question is, would this be considered unprofessional?

Edit - This is not similar to the other questions I found as I'm asking about professionalism before and after work as opposed to the ethics of doing it.

Comment: I guess it is up to you what you don in your free time. Unprofessional is when you play games on working hours. However I would avoid to install games in your work machine and if possible get out of work space if you are not working. It is possible to say in some where that is not strictly a work space ?

Comment: An adult playing games at a workplace, regardless of whether or not they're "clocked-in" or "given permission" is going to create an immediate unprofessional impression. Such impressions will do damage even if nothing is ever said. Just don't do it and don't even ask.

Comment: I was once in a very similar situation - playing games on my phone at my desk at lunch. My then manager had a chat with me, and said that in his own youth he would play cards with fellow employees in the lunch room on their break. One day he was pulled aside by his own manager, and told that when the higher ups see him playing games on his lunch they question his fitness to evolve into management material, and that it's come up tangentially in some conversations. The take-away was that while it's your own time and your own equipment, playing games in the office can have a negative perception.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49122/discussion-on-question-by-tfish-is-it-unprofessional-of-me-to-play-games-before).

Comment: @teego1967 I feel that in a lot of 'newer' workspaces, especially in the software development industry, that this is entirely *not true*. As long as the manager knows that you're not just slacking off, I highly doubt that anyone would think anything differently of you for playing games. I have a friend who works in the SD industry who has an hour break at work where most of his coworkers play games together after eating lunch. Seems to me that most people, at least in our industry, are quite relaxed about things like gaming.

Comment: @Tfish Why not start work early, and then leave early? As long as you clear this with your manager, you should be fine.

Comment: I work in an office of about a hundred people, at a company of about 600. Six of us or so play games like Quake and Ultimate Chicken Horse for an hour at the end of the day (I even get in at noon and start playing at 430 then go back to work after), We're even getting a TV dedicated to gaming installed. This is a hard question to answer because it depends entirely of what everyone else does. I'd say this all depends on the culture. If no one else is doing it, don't, but otherwise make sure it's cool.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on office culture and politics. That said, if you have to ask this question the chances are that you are better off taking your time off—on your own—and leaving the office to play games in a park or cafe or somewhere else. Even if your time off in the office is your time off, humans—being the social animals we are—will see behavior like that as being “childish” and inappropriate for the workplace.

Comment: @teego1967 I suspect if my employer felt the same way you did, they would not have paid money to install gaming consoles at the office.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you can't simply start working an hour early and then also leave an hour early? Otherwise I strongly suggest you bring up the idea of flexible work hours with your management. For software developers flexible work hours should be standard practice regardless of seniority.

Comment: @emory, I think you'd be surprised how many workplaces DON'T have a romper room, foosball, nor petting zoo. The fact is not all employers and more importantly not all coworkers and managers will see playing games as acceptable for a working age adult. Ironically, I see nothing wrong with gaming, but realize that many people will silently and irreversibly judge such behaviors in a negative way. Just trying to save the OP some grief.

Comment: @teego1967 - dude that's literally the argument people are giving you. The companies are different, your first comment is completelly dogmatic and pretend it's everywhere the same.

Comment: @teego1967 I think I see ur point.  If OP's employer had like mine provided the consoles, then it would be totally obvious gaming is OK and OP would not have even asked the question.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

As long as people are aware you are not currently working, then there is no issue. You may not want to do this at your desk, but instead in a break room. This way people will not mistake you for thinking you're playing whilst you are supposed to be working.

After all, you're not on the clock, what you do during your time is up to you and not for someone else to judge. Just make it clear you are not currently on the clock.

Comment: Yes, doing this at your desk would create the wrong impression.  also keep in mind that it's easy to lose track of time when you're playing games.  I get in to the office 90 mins before anyone else for the same kind of reason.  I tend to catch up on emails, tech blogs, news, etc. before starting work early.  I start early and leave early to beat the traffic.

Comment: Making your manager aware of your working pattern is the most important action to avoid the wrong impression.  I agree there is no issue, but the potential for a misunderstanding is significant.

Comment: @dan1111 Hence why you have to make it very clear you are currently not on the clock. Doing it at your desk is a bad idea unless people are aware of the situation. Doing it in a break room would suggest to people you are currently not working.

Comment: @Draken, then people may wonder why you spend so much of your work day in the break room, instead of wondering why you are goofing off at your desk.  In any case, there's no harm in informing your manager.  And it's much better to do this pro-actively rather than waiting until someone complains (an after the fact explanation may come across as excuse making).

Comment: @dan1111 Even if you get your manager confirmation, people could still complain. Getting permission doesn't change anything other than warning the manager they may get these comments. If anything, the manager should be able to see the employee's current working hours, realise the timings and put two and two together and inform people that they are doing the requested number of hours a day. In the end, as long as the person is doing the correct number of hours of work, how long they spend in the break room is no one else's business, apart from their manager's and themselves.

Comment: One additional thing: If the games require some sort of internet connection *and* you use your companies infrastructure to connect to the internet even from the break room, then you should nonetheless check / get permission that you're allowed to use the company's infrastructure for this.

Comment: "As long as people are aware you are not currently working, then there is no issue." As long as you mean "no firing offense", well most likely (although not a given). If you really mean "can have no negative repercussions" I'll have to disagree, because that strongly depends on the environment and job. There are many environments where this will leave a negative impression with higher management (which are generally older) which can certainly influence promotion opportunities.

Comment: @Voo That's a very old sentiment, how is this any different than reading a book when you are on a break at work?

Comment: @Draken And luckily higher management is always particularly young and modern and humans are always oh so rational. In theory it shouldn't matter, but in practice it does - understanding this is one of those things that distinguishes young starry eyed grads from the more experienced.

Comment: @Voo I'll remember that, after my previous 10 years of experience, I should change my habits. Not all socks fit the same feet and I've never had such an issue being caused by me playing video games during breaks and my own personal time. But as we've got with other answers, it seems to depend on the location and people you're working with. As long as people have a hard work ethic, I don't see how someone having some leisure time, during their own time, would affect my view of them

Comment: @Draken I'd certainly hope that it wouldn't even unconsciously affect me either and I absolutely wouldn't want to work for such a company. But these companies do exist and unconscious biases are a problem.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect for many companies.  Please be careful that you aren't just confirming what you want to hear.

Answer (score 76):

This really depends on the company and policies. Some companies have strict policies about what you can do in their space. I know this sounds harsh, but keep in mind that you are using a space rented by the company you are working for.

I have worked in companies where 70% of the employees would do what you are doing, together with the manager and they even organized gaming nights without any issue at all. This was due to the fact that the manager was open and wanted to make a good working space (and not only) for the employees.

You need to ask your superior (even in writing) for the permission if this type of activity is not something that others do freely.

Comment: Never seen a company saying what you can and cannot do in a break room, maybe at your desk, but when you're not working? I'd love to see an example of that

Comment: why the downvote? The most ethical thing to do is ask your manager/superior if you can spend your free time at the office. It is not something which you can do by default. Some companies in my country have time-tracking tools and the law requires them to define routes to and from work for employees. If you have an accident on the route, it is considered a work accident. Now, if you stay late at the office it might still be considered a work accident, even if you were just spending your free time there. Of course, this would happen in very extreme conditions (lawsuits, etc.).

Comment: I gave you a reason, the blanket statement that a company can control what you can and cannot do across the entire company site is rather daft. If you have an example, I'm more than happy to remove said downvote, just edit it into the answer.

Comment: I cannot give you an example, as this would trigger privacy issues for those companies. I know for a fact, that some companies have strict issues about activities at their site. It's not even only 1 example, I know several.

Comment: Stating a HR policy would break a company's privacy? Since when? I could understand not giving away sensitive information, but how a company regulates the people who works there, that's just odd

Comment: Think about it like this: some companies have time-tracking tools that when you get into the office, by using the access card, your time is counted. When you leave the office the counter is stopped. Now, if you stay and play games after work, you are considered as working (extra hours).

Comment: @TurbutAlin - If there were strong policies about how time was used on company property, then the OP would (should) be aware of this.  We don't usually have such strict policies here in the UK except where the workplace is secure/sensitive (banks for example).

Comment: I'm in one of those offices that has a door tracking software to see how many hours we are on site, we also use software where we have to enter our hours in and what we did. We have an hour unpaid lunch break, by your rules, I was working during my lunch as I was in the building. Companies cannot and should not rely on a door entry card to track the number of hours worked. If they want that, they need to use a clocking in machine that is separate from the door.

Comment: The companies I was talking about are actually outsourcing companies for banks, but still it is worth mentioning that the OP or anyone reading this should be aware of all circumstances. Of course, in 90-95% of the cases, the companies don't have strict policies.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to run it by your manager.  That is right, as even if there is no problem with it, the potential for misunderstanding is there.

Comment: There is also the insurance thing. In many countries, you are covered by the company's insurance while you're at work and while you are going to and back from work. If you for example stay an additional two to three hours in the office after work to have beers provided by your startup every day, where does this insurance coverage start and end? What if you fall down the stairs? Who's fault is it? Those things should be considered.

Comment: +1 absolutely this depends on the company and the culture. Talk to your boss and gauge his reaction, if he says "Oooookay" with a frown it isn't ;) I used to head out to a local pub and read for an hour instead. Gives you a break from the office as well.

Comment: @Draken Do you disagree with the statement that a company absolutely can decide what you can and cannot do on its property, or is this a case of "I've never heard of this, so it cannot exist"?

Comment: @Voo I do not, however I disagree with any company putting that much force into effect across the entire site. If the activity is not causing any harm to the company, then there is no issue. Playing a video game on your own console whilst in a break room is not something any company should worry about when they have bigger fish to fry

Comment: @Draken never seen a company that doesn't regulate what you can do with company property, which includes the company owned computers and network hardware.

Comment: @jwenting Agreed, however the OP said: *but I would rather be playing games on my phone or on my DS.* That's not company property.

Comment: @Draken I'm not sure why you're still arguing this. You may not have seen companies dictate what is and isn't acceptable during breaks but the simple fact is that they can and of course should do so. A simple example that I hope we can all agree on is that people shouldn't watch porn in the break room. Feel free to pick more realistic or absurd examples if you'd like but these restrictions are entirely common. Some companies would in fact ban games of any kind from being played on site and there can be good and bad reasons for such a ban. This answer makes a perfectly valid point.

Answer (score 45):

This is about *image management*. If you habitually play games at the office, you'll probably be labeled in various ways. None of them are positive.

When you miss a deadline, they will say, "Maybe if he worked instead of playing games..."

When you code a bug... "Maybe if he thought about something other than playing games..."

When someone can't remember your name - "You know, that guy who plays games all the time..."

These people may not really understand that you're doing this on your own time (if on company equipment and property...)

I once worked with a guy known as "The guy who is outside smoking all the time". The quality, completeness, and timeliness of his work wasn't mentioned by the label, only that he wasn't at his desk.

So manage your image while you are at work. Do not give haters and detractors ammunition. A damaged image can cause you to lose tie-breakers. When employees are stack-ranked, bonuses are allocated depending on rank. You'll lose when all else is equal.  When someone complains to your boss, using the "playing games all the time" argument (regardless of the accuracy), your boss is on the defensive, at best. Your boss doesn't want to have to defend the perception that he thinks it is OK for the staff to play games at work. *Don't put your boss into this position.*

I knew one programmer who would work on electronics projects over lunch. While a completely constructive (and fun!) activity, it made it look like he wanted to be somewhere else. This is a negative and is a tie-breaker.

I have personally seen cases where one staffer was deemed "not yet ready" for a plum assignment. Tie-breakers did him in.

And I know this view people might have of you is not fair. And how they might use it against you is not fair. What's that got to do with anything?

Comment: Exactly! And it is not only about your boss but also about the motivation for your colleagues. Imagine that Alice is working late, to make an extra effort voluntarily in a busy period. First Bob runs away, he apologetically mentions something about feeding his kids. 15 minutes later Mark closes his laptop and happily and openly starts to play games for 1 hour while Alice is struggling. -- Now, which person might expect a frown from Alice?

Comment: If they are blaming negative things on the gaming even though he works for the contracted time, it is them that aren't acting professional.

Comment: @bunyaCloven Maybe they don't know his hours. Regardless, the OP will damage himself regardless of whether it is fair or not.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and a nice intro to office politics for a junior developer, many of whom don't understand that this kind of thing actually goes on.  Sometimes you don't get a chance to explain yourself and people just form their own conclusions... and those conclusions can have a real impact on your career, whether they are justified or not.

Comment: The first sentence is great and the rest just ignores any possible difference in culture.

Comment: +1 for "tie-breaker".  Critical thing to consider for managing image.

Comment: "When employees are stack ranked" you should find a different job.

Comment: @Timbo I did, in fact ;-) But a lot of companies do it, if informally. When the boss cuts up the bonuses, there is frequently some leeway. Then tie-breakers matter.

Answer (score 39):

> this leaves me with a conundrum, because I could work that extra hour and not get paid. 
>   I can browse websites like Facebook, Twitter or the Workplace Stack
>   but I would rather be playing games on my phone or on my DS.
>
> So my main question is, would this be considered unprofessional?

You have an extra hour on your hands and you have already decided that you will stay at work that hour.

Here's what I think of the options, ranked in order of perceived professionalism:

- Working an extra hour can show dedication, extra effort, and the desire to get ahead.
- Browsing websites shows a bit less dedication, but can convey a learning attitude, particularly if you stick to websites related to your profession
- Playing games shows that you work to the clock and play games on your off time

If *professionalism* is your concern here (as you specifically stated, rather than health or work/life balance for example), I'd suggest either working or going somewhere else where your management won't see you to play your games.

Imagine you are the boss. You walk around the office and can't help but notice who is around before or after hours, and if people are working or playing games. What do you imagine would make the most professional or the least professional impression? I suspect the answer is pretty clear. Now as the employee, you get to decide if you care what your boss thinks or not and what kind of impression you would prefer to make.

Comment: I will say, that having a boss to walk around to see who's all professional and such... those are things that typically don't belong in companies in western europe. In fact, it's typically an american thing. Yes, every boss wants professional employees. However in europe the distance between bosses, managers and employees are much smaller. In europe companies try to build a long lasting "relationship" with the employee. In america you're just another person they can replace. Professionalism mainly matters just towards the customer. often not internally.

Comment: @Joe working longer than your contract says is not working hard. At best, it's cheating yourself, and at worst it's detrimental to your health and in consequence it's bad for the company because you could get sick and be gone, or stop doing it while the company learns to rely on unsolicited extra efforts by employees. When I manage people, I tend to send them home if I notice they stay too long because I prefer rested, motivated people over work-product that was done by someone tired who can't concentrate any more just to be done faster.

Comment: @Joe for completion I should probably add how software developers are often treated in western europe. As a software developer, I'm given a large amount of freedom to do what I want. most companies here try to lure in software developers with pleasant and stress free working enviroments. Very often developers who could earn 6k monthly are satisfied with getting 4k because of these enviroments. This happens in both smaller and larger companies. Your points still stand and is very valid, but I feel like they would be less crucial in the UK. which is where OP is from.

Comment: @Joe I was referring to the part about the manager taking note of what people do before and after working hours while they are still there. Working a bit more once in a while is certainly not a problem, but if it gets to a point where the manager is acutely aware of the fact that someone works way more than they are supposed to then in my opinion they should be sent home. Staying longer and doing something else is certainly not a problem to your health, but that was not my argument anyway.

Comment: @Migz I'm also based in the UK (in the software field, too) and I don't agree with your characterization.  While the overall expectation of working hours/effort is different, in many workplaces it will certainly get noticed which employees put in extra and which work the bare minimum.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, great answer. I would add that it's not just about your boss seeing you working or not.  If you work that extra time it should also be reflected in greater output.

Comment: I would take exception to the "works to the clock".  While it could be true, i.e. everyday at EOD + 2 seconds he's got his game up and running, it's not necessarily true per the question.

Comment: @simbabque agreed. Way too many people feel the need to join the rat race, be the first in, last out, always at maximum stress levels, so they're not seen as "lazy" or "unmotivated" by managers which will lead them to end up on the next list of layoffs. Been there, done that, got the burnout. Learned the hard way that if your managers don't care about you except for where your breaking point is and keeping you just shy of it, you'd be better off not working there.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere  Spending the extra time working rather than a leisure activity can indeed be detrimental to both physical and mental health.  More and more data are being published on the effects of overworking, if you research the topic I think you will begin to understand the difference.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere - Just search google for 'overworking healthy'.  There is a ton of info from highly regarded sources.  No need for me to go into details in comments.  Also I was replying to your comment about not understanding how spending this extra 60 minutes or so working rather than a doing a non-work related leisure activity is detrimental to ones health.  I agree, lets not pretend, its fact that playing games in moderation can be relaxing and stress relieving and thus more healthy.  Again tons of research data available.  The professional aspect is already well covered in this thread.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere  I was addressing your comment regarding health in hopes to enlighten you.  Appears thats not going to happen so I will just drop it and move on.

Answer (score 8):

The existing answers look at the narrow issue of the effect on others of seeing you playing games. This answer goes to the broader issue of life as a software professional.

You have embarked on a career that requires life long learning. Maybe you already know everything that would be in any way useful for your current job, but do you know everything you are going to need next year? In two years?

As an alternative to playing games, use the time to study. Bring in technical books to read. Have a laptop loaded up with a development environment for the next programming language, framework, or development strategy you are going to learn.

You could learn a lot in 90 minutes per working day of study and practice.

When I was a project leader, I several times saw one of my junior developers studying a textbook at lunch time. That made a strong positive impression, when playing games would have been neutral, since I knew it was a break time.

Answer (score 7):

I would say this also hinges upon the work environment itself.  There are companies out in the Tech sector that do not frown on these activities when off the clock.

Now, if I were working at, lets say an investment firm or a law enforcement call center, I would not be gaming off the clock, at least not while at my desk.

Maybe in the break room on a personal device that was geared towards that purpose, if company policy allowed for it.

Answer (score 6):

You should ask your supervisor if it's okay for you to do it. Don't ask us at the Workplace, we don't set policy at your workplace and we can't interpret policy at your workplace that we don't know about. Your question is workplace-specific by the way: what's okay at one workplace would get you written up at another that's much more conservative and corporate. Or run by pointy headed management.

I used to work for a consulting company. I was eating a quick lunch at the desk that the client had assigned to me and reading a magazine from a magazine rack that the client had provided for the employees' reading. One of the client's managers saw me making myself at home, badgered me and complained to my management. My management followed up and harassed the hell out of me. At any other workplace but this one, I think nobody would have cared.

If you are in doubt about a company policy, ask. And ask the company, not us.

Answer (score 6):

"Is it professional of me to play games" This alone results in a "no". However, whatever you do in your own time is up to you.

However when you use your free time at work, it might get complicated. It depends on the company. you'd need to ask yourself several questions.

1. Do customers walk around the company in the hours you're playing games?
2. Do other employees know of your hours? Does it matter?
3. How strict is the business culture?

If customers walk around the company and see you playing games, that leaves a bad image to the company. While the customer may/may not care, your superiors absolutely will. At this point they wont care if you were on break or off work ot not. Of-course the break room is an exception.

In a more strict 9 to 5 company they will not enjoy having their employees making weird hours or doing non-working activities. In those cultures other employees will often try to copy such behaviour and possibly lower productivity.

In a less strict company, employees coudln't care less what you do during and outside of your working time. Mainly because it doesn't affect them. In such a culture you'd be able to play games whenever you want, for as long as you end up making the hours. (I doubt this is the care for your company)

As suggested before, going for the break room would be the 100% safe solution. I've only seen a few companies that have an xbox in the break-room but whenever anyone were to play on it on their break, all managers and other employees would give you weird looks. Again, it depends on the company's culture.

---

If you end up being unable to figure this out on your own, talk to your manager. Most managers tend to have weekly or bi-weekly 1-on-1 conversations with their employees, if you dont have one, ask for one. or simply walk by his office if he has one.

If your manager doesn't have either of these. As in no weekly conversations or personal office. Then I'd still try to catch him somewhere in private. I wouldn't feel comfortable having other employees weighing in on this topic.

Furthermore, While you might be in off-hours. You're still available at work. This in itself is quite valuable for the company. They dont need to pay you for being available, which is in their own benefit. You know, in case they need to ask you a small question.

Comment: A very good point about customers (+1)

Comment: Sidenote regarding 9-5. Actually I would say that only if everyone finishes at the same time, and working late is extremely rare, then it may be reasonable to openly game at work 'after 5'. (Assuming the building is open anyway, for instance because it is shared with another company)

Answer (score 3):

While it isn't unprofessional, it is pretty much guaranteed to create a negative impression to **some** of the employees and customers.

Unfortunately, people have a tendency to judge and condemn without having complete and accurate information. **Some** will assume you're gaming instead of working, and **some** others will assume you're childish and irresponsible because you play games.

It will be better for your career to play games some distance away from the workplace, like the coffee shop down the road. Ironically it's the unprofessional prejudices of **some** people that lead to this advice - it's not about gaming being professional or not, but about unprofessional people judging you.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it wouldn't look so good to play games.

I would say that instead, use that time to do some work, and then take some time off in the middle of the day to go for a run or the gym.

Just an idea, and it might be suitable in your situation, but the benefits are multiple, and you would *look* more professional.

Answer (score 0):

I would mention that besides being clocked in or not that you need to consider the equipment and data lines. If you are using your data and your network then you might have a case to compare to playing cards. But if you are using the company equipment in any way for leisurely access to the machine or networking you are out of line and may be putting your company at unnecessary security risk. Then the question of image comes in after that.

We played internally network games over lunch hour and it affected those who worked over the lunch hour. And of course once we accessed externally they went berserk. Thinking of recent dDos attacks in USA those who work on that part of the business would not appreciate having to track down extra traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Others may not know that you are not "clocked in" while doing obviously not work-relevant things at work. Even if you document your working hours somewhere, they probably do not have access to this information.

So they may assign the negative image of you that may initially look for them deserved but also stick for later, even after you have clarified the situation. The bigger the company, the bigger this problem is.

Additionally, the company may not like you using your workstation, network and office space for personal things, even if this does not cost them much in addition to that they already pay.

Comment: heh, I can see OP making a "not clocked in" placard, like the folded plastic cards you place on your table when you order food at a fast-food location.